# How to know if document was saved in MongoDb after save() method?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am saving my document in MongoDb and using save method with class,collection name param.

All the methods of save and insert are void return type. then how i can know that my document was saved or not.

Is it that i have to re-query to check whether my document was saved. I just need any return value to see if it was saved.

Moreover i am using Spring Data for Mongo to do operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what `WriteConcern` are you using. If you use `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED`, 
the operation will wait for an acknowledgement from the primary server, so if no exception is raised, the record has been saved correctly. Otherwise you should be able to query `WriteResult`

```
WriteResult writeResult=mycollection.insert(record);
if (writeResult.getError() != null) {
    throw new Exception(String.format("Insertion wasn't successful: %s",writeResult));
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository

returns a list of the saved objects:

```
<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entites);
```

or in

```
CrudRepository
```

you have

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

which provides the saved object. That object will have a whatever field you annotated with @Id with a value filled in different to null after it has successfully been persisted.