# how to check if mongoTemplate.save is successfully saved documents as mongoTemplate.save returns void

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am saving documents to MongoDB, but not getting exception even if mongo insertion or save not happened.

If mongo server failure occurs by chance then the particular document saves at that time should be taken care by validating its insertion or save in MongoDB.

Even I tried to use writeResult object (as with writeResult we can check last object transaction status )status for mongoTemplate.save but its returning void, not writeResult obj.

I need to know if there is any way to check success when saving/insertion of monogtemplate.save.

**This is how I am saving document.**

mongoTemplate.save(obj, CollectionName);

**MongoConfiguration class:**

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String mongoURI;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String databaseName;



    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoURI));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }    

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how we would know if document was saved in Mongodb after save() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867680/how-we-would-know-if-document-was-saved-in-mongodb-after-save-method)

Comment: in above post they have used WriteResult as myCollection.insert return WriteResult object, my query is that insert or save method returning void, so how to implement WriteResult for validating success save?

Comment: Ideally, Insert ,save or any method in MongoTemplate does not return true or false.But it will throw RuntimeExceptions if anything failed

Comment: You could use writeresult as WriteResult writeResult=yourcollection.save(record);

Comment: For WriteResult writeResult=mongoTemplate.save(record), I am getting Type mismatch- cannot convert from void to WriteResult.

Comment: What if you use yourcollection.insert(record)  rather than save() ?

Comment: insert also returning void, so typeMismatch error.

Comment: what if you use record=mongoTemplate.save(record) ? Will record hold any update value

Comment: save or insert returns nothing so couldn't assign it to any other object.

Comment: Is that a version mismatch? Not sure. Ideally `WriteResult saveResult = collection.save(instance);` should be matched. Could you please refer this and try. https://www.javatips.net/api/com.mongodb.writeresult